# Alternative Comment Method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a CMS that minifies all scripts automatically and need to add a disclaimer as a comment the top of the .js file.

These work with most minifiers but **don't work** with whatever one they're using:

```
/*! This is the disclaimer */
/* @license This is the disclaimer */
/* @preserve This is the disclaimer */
```

I'm trying to find any other alternative that won't break the script. The page it's used on will also have jQuery if that adds more options.

So far my only solution seems to turn it into a string, but I'm not sure if this okay in all browsers even though it doesn't seem to break anything in most.

```
"This is the disclaimer";

// Rest of code here
```

I'd rather not do the following since it makes the disclaimer a little bit less obvious and I want it to stand out:

```
var c="This is the disclaimer";

// Rest of code here
```

Suggestions / ideas?

Comment: Which tool do you use to minify?

Comment: Most minifying software has some method of leaving a comment for this exact purpose. which software you're using ?

Comment: I would have to reach out to the CMS development team to determine which minifier they're using.

Comment: You said you have a problem with a tool, but didn't say which tool. How can we help you here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string will be fine.

What proof do I have of that assertion?

Well, there's a reason they chose this:

```
"use strict";
```

as the activator for Strict Mode, and that is that it wouldn't interfere with browsers that don't support it.

So provided your disclaimer isn't "use strict", you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

Which tool do you use to minify?
For example, with [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) you can use a `!` to keep one comment:

```
/*!
 * This is the DISCLAIMER
 */
```